# "comme toujours" vs. "comme depuis toujours"

Tags: choix-de-mot

Is there any difference between "comme toujours" and "comme depuis toujours"?

[image]

I see that on the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+toujours%2Ccomme+depuis+toujours&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccomme%20toujours%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20toujours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BComme%20toujours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccomme%20depuis%20toujours%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20depuis%20toujours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BComme%20depuis%20toujours%3B%2Cc0) that "comme depuis toujours" is much less used. Is that even a valid expression?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that:

- *Comme depuis toujours* means *as usual*, and refers to past behavior: the current behavior resembles the typical past behavior.
- *Comme toujours* means *as always*, and - at least in principle - applies to both past and future behavior. In other words, not only has this been the case in the past, but it is expected to remain the case in the future.

And no, I'm not sure that *comme depuis toujours* is "legitimate" frog-speak. ;-) But I've certainly heard it.

Comment: Instead of *as always* as a translation of *comme toujours*, maybe *since forever* could be more accurate or more explicit.

Comment: @popo: To me, "*since forever*" conveys *comme depuis toujours*: **since** refers to a past moment and implies **until now**. It suggests nothing about the future. On its own, *forever* would suggest including the future, but its scope is limited by applying *since*. What is really meant by *since forever* is that the "*since*" moment was the beginning of time (or before time ;-)). IOW, it is forever backward in time, not forward.

Comment: it's been like this *since forever*, suggests that it's gonna continue to be so, no? So there's an implicit reference to future... But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: @popo *Depuis toujours*, synonyme *de tout temps, depuis la nuit des temps*, et des expressions signifiant que l'on ne perçoit pas l'origine de l'habitude, qu'il s'agit d'une tradition, d'un usage établi de longue date. Ajouter *comme* devant marque une insistance pour marquer l'incident en cours ... *crôôâââ, crôôâââ :)*

Comment: @popo: No, it does not suggest that it's going to continue to be so. It suggests only that it has been this way forever (in the past). The *forever* here refers to an infinite stretch of time, from the present moment backward.

Comment: yes i guess you're right! I was a bit tired when i added the comment, and today i think i disagree with my yesterday-old self ;-)

Comment: It happens. ;-)